# how to get export data from sopui response to a excel file

Tags: soapui

Im trying to export data from response to a excel so that i can do excel comparison to validate actual data which is already saved in excel format.Can you someone has any idea or sample code to do this in Soapui pro? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI-Pro has the [DataSink Teststep](http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/datasink-teststep.html) which will dump data to Excel format.

Comment: I did consider DataSink but the one problem, we need to mention Tag/Node name for the data. Im looking to get the entire data along with the tag/node name to the excel. Do you think i can still use Datasink? Can i automate this process ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you explain me ? If you have the code to intiate datasink?

Comment: Have you read through the link I posted? What have you tried? What did not work?